# C# - .NET: Create an HTTP POST API call to VulDB Vulnerability Database - "API key missing"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, post

I am currently developing a web application using .NET, and trying to request data from the VulDB vulnerability database via their API. In their documentation, they specify the process as follows (Source: https://vuldb.com/de/?kb.api):

> To start an API query you have to do an HTTP POST request to the following resource:
>
> https://vuldb.com/?api
>
> [...]
>
> Every request must include your personal API key. You may propose it as part of the POST data with the field apikey (you must enter the key without the brackets):
>
> apikey=[your_personal_api_key]

I tried doing the POST by following the Microsoft tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient#http-post

I followed the same tutorial earlier to create a GET request for another API, and it worked just fine.

Here is what I tried.

```
        public async Task<String> PostAsync()
        {
            using StringContent jsonContent = new(
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                {
                    apikey="hereIsActuallyMyAPIKey",
                    recent=10
                }),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");

            using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync("", jsonContent);

            var statusCode = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Unfortunately, the response from the API says that the API key is missing.

```
{"response":
    {"version": "3.54",
     "format": "json",
     "status": "401",
     "lang": "en",
     "error": "API key missing",
     "querylimitmax": 0,
     [...]
}
```

Did I formulate my request false? I would love to get some pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a valid POST request by using the third party tool RestSharp (https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107). It allows the passing of parameters like this:

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://vuldb.com/de/?api");
            var request = new RestRequest("");
            request.AddHeader("X-VulDB-ApiKey", "APIKeyValue");
            request.AddParameter("recent", "10");

            var response = client.Post(request);
            return response.Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass the Api Key via the header ?

On the documentation of VulDB API, I can read

> As an alternative it is possible to use it as a custom HTTP request header named X VulDB-ApiKey:
>
> X-VulDB-ApiKey: [your_personal_api_key]

You can add your API key to the header with the code

```cs
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-VulDB-ApiKey", "hereIsActuallyYourAPIKey");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When using the custom header the API accepts the key, but then returns the status code `405: Unknown Request`, likely due to an "empty" request. Do you know where to pass additional parameters like the `recent=10` I did above, or is this API specific? Adding a second header like `_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("recent", "10");` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe add the `recent=10` to the body like you used to ?

Comment: That didn't work either. But I managed to solve it by using a 3rd party library, I posted the answer below. Thanks for your help! :)